# How do I send data from my database (Firebase Firestore) to my React Native app?

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, expo

I'm running into a small issue here.

The problem: I'm trying to send data from a Firebase Cloud Function (using Node.js) connected to Firestore, to my react native app. I have a [trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) that activates when a document is added to Firestore, and I would like to add data to redux (in my app) when the trigger activates.

I know I have to send information within a trigger function like the one below, but I'm not exactly sure how one would send data directly to the expo app.

```
// Example trigger function
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    // Send information to React Native App
  });
```

I understand to send information *to* a database you simply make a fetch or axios post, but to send information *from* the database has my mind boggled.

Any help or point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is going to be active on the device already, the common approach would be to write the notification for that app to a different collection and have the app [listen on that collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

If the app may not be in use on the device, the common approach is to [send a notification through FCM to the device](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).